# Java breakpoint on Linux syscall

Tags: java, linux, breakpoints, system-calls

How could I have a breakpoint in Java that's triggered when a native method calls (directly or indirectly) a certain Linux syscall?

Comment: A very strange requirement. Can you explain the backgrounds, so that perhaps other ways to solve your problem can be found?

Comment: I want to look at arbitrary applications that I did not write, and conveniently determine why they are telling the OS to do certain things. I am dissatisfied with just putting a breakpoint on Java API calls, because there may be more than one way to do something, and anyway that doesn't work at all for OS calls from custom JNI code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a breakpoint, but at least it gives you a stack trace, which may be all you need. Furthermore, the Systemtap language does allow you to do more stuff than just print stack traces, if you need to.

In the IcedTea JVM source code, you will find a [SystemTap file](http://icedtea.classpath.org/hg/icedtea6/file/tip/tapset/jstack.stp.in) with functions that can be used to get stack traces from a running IcedTea (with Hotspot) JVM. As I understand it, with these functions you can get a Java stack trace from any event that SystemTap supports - even from in-kernel events.

Note that despite having the same name, these jstack functions are unrelated to the jstack(1) command-line utility supplied with the JDK. They work via memory inspection, not via calling back to the JVM, so they are [quite specific to Hotspot internals](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/gdb/2012-02/msg00034.html), and therefore probably won't work with non-Hotspot-based JVMs.

Note: [Systemtap does not fully work on default Debian kernels](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnDebian), so you may need to compile your own kernel on Debian-based systems. This problem does not affect Fedora or Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it would be possible to native-compile the application using an ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler for Java, and then use a native debugger to set a breakpoint or catchpoint on the syscall. (Bonus: You then get a complete stack trace including all the C functions called by the native method, and the ability to debug those C functions seamlessly.)

You would probably want to use a debugger which knew how to demangle names produced by the AOT compiler. For example, gdb knows how to demangle names produced by gcj, so a gcj combination with gdb should work.

The trouble with this combination is that gcj is still stuck at **partial** JDK 1.5 compatibility, and no-one has bothered to do the work of merging in the OpenJDK class library (it was suggested on the gcj mailing list in 2009). And as a result, gcj has never been a popular option - people do often use it unintentionally (particularly on Debian and Ubuntu), but then when they hit a problem they tend to switch to a more standard JDK instead of reporting a bug.

Native compilation with an AOT compiler is also much slower than just letting the JRE JIT-compile code when it thinks it's necessary.